# How to re-inflate layout from outside of onCreateView

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-relativelayout

I am stuck with an android project which is done by my colleague. Right now I have no time to do it correctly.
I am stuck in a situation where I have to re-inflate a layout from outside of `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

There is a `public static void showRecords()` method which is called from outside the Fragment, and in that method I am trying to inflate the layout by doing this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formshowlayout, null);

//RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout3);

TextView txtValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
txtValue.setText("some text to show");
```

I am getting no exception or error, and also the TextView "some text to show" is not showing either.

In android is it possible to do what am I doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify a parent `ViewGroup` and inflate the view into it.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formshowlayout, container, true);
```

where `container` is the hierarchical parent of the new view.